# I created a R function that includes for loop inside and return() function, but it did not generate the correct result

Tags: r, function

I'm learning R functions. I tried to create a my_variance function. This is the code:

```
my_variance <- function(d){
 variance <- 0
 m <- mean(d)
 for (i in d){
   v <- i-m
   variance <- variance + v
 }
 return(variance)
}
```

Then I tried a vector:

```
my_variance(1:33)
```

But the result generated in R is:

```
[1] 0
```

Could anybody explain what is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `^2` here: `v <- (i-m)^2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are commiting a statistical mistake. The sum

```
sum(x - mean(x))
```

is **always** zero. And this is what your code is computing.
You are also forgetting to divide by `length(d) - 1` or by `length(d)` if you prefer the ML estimator.

The correct way would be

```
my_variance <- function(d){
  n <- length(d)
  variance <- 0
  m <- mean(d)
  for (i in d){
    v <- (i - m)^2
    variance <- variance + v
  }
  variance/(n - 1)
}

my_variance(1:33)
#[1] 93.5

var(1:33)
#[1] 93.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand my mistakes now.